# How to update custom metric using Sonar API

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have added a custom metric in my sonarqube. Want to update this metric value from a standalone analyser in C#.

I have tried with Sonar Web API @https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392172 ,

but seems these are changed and not working anymore.

Got the apis by accessing "mysonarserver/api" and framed the request as below

"http://mysonarserver/api/metrics/update?id=MetricID&key=MetricKey&name=MetricName&description=MetricDescription";

but how to get the id of the metric which i have added manually?

Also how to update the value of the metric from Sonar Web API, as in the above i can only update the metric description and its key but not its value provided if I pass the MetricID which i dont have.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: below are some more detail                                                                    First  I have added a custom metric through Administration->Configuration->CustomMetrics. Then the same metric added to  project level by clicking on individual project ->Administration->Custom Measures. Now iam trying to update the project level metric value thru sonar api. "mysonarserver/api/custom_measures/update?id=140&name=metricname&projectKey=projectkey&value=18&description=description" , but its giving me error  measure with id =140  not found , though created the metric with Id 140

Comment: please [edit] these details into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The ID has to be obtained through another query to sonar server "http://sonarserver/api/custom_measures/search?f=metric&isCustom=true&projectKey=myprojectkey" then  we get metric details in JSON format , parse it for Id field and passed this Id value to update query to update the metric value.

update query:
http://sonarserver/api/custom_measures/update?id=MetricIdObtainedAbove &name=MetricName&projectKey=myprojectKeyInSonar&value=metricvaluetoupdate